# Using color variable in TikZ before they are declared

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to use the color of a path to set the color of the nodes. But I want the nodes to be lighter than the path color. And I want to do this before knowing what the path color will be. Hence, how do i get what will be active path color, so that I can adjust the node color?

Comment: Could you give a hypothetical example of what you'd like to be able to write?  I'm finding it hard to envision a case where the node does not know the colour of the path that it is on.

Comment: @Andrew: if the color is declared (then changed) in a style, the `\draw[style]` command may not know what color that is.

Comment: @Matthew: I was thinking of hacking in to the lower level code and having the node look at the macro that holds the path's colour.

Answer (score 4):

TikZ/PGF uses `xcolor` to store and manipulate color values. With `xcolor` the current color is always available as `.`. So, you can write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[red!50!blue]
        \fill[radius=1cm] circle 
            node[font={\bf\huge}] {\color{.!20}text};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

to obtain

[image: result]

Comment: *Very* useful!!

Comment: @Matthew: Also have a look on `\blendcolors`. You might find it also very useful. However IIRC it doesn't work for the current color just for subsequent ones.

Comment: Thank you @peter and @PeterSmith for your comments!  Here the problem in more detail:

Comment: Here is a sample that illustrates what I get \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes}
\definecolor{currentPathcolor}{rgb}{0.8 0.4 0.2}
\tikzstyle{pathstyle}=[>=latex,>->,dashed]
\tikzstyle{nodestyle}=[ellipse,inner sep=1pt,text=black,fill=.!20]
\tikzstyle{nodestyleX}=[ellipse,inner sep=1pt,text=black,fill=currentPathcolor!20]
\tikzstyle{mystyle}=[scale= .5,  
baseline=(current bounding box.center),
style1/.style={ out=45,in=120,distance=3cm, line width=1.1pt},
style2/.style={ out=-45,in=-120,distance=3cm, min distance=2cm, line width=1.1pt}
]

Comment: Sorry having trouble getting the latex code in.

Comment: Not enough characters allowed to enter my sample. In short: \tikzstyle{nodestyle}=[ellipse,inner sep=1pt,text=black,fill=.!20]
 
\tikzstyle{nodestyleX}=[ellipse,inner sep=1pt,text=black,fill=currentPathcolor!20]%The PROBLEM: How to get the yet unknown current path color

(m-2-3) edge [style1, out=90, in=90,distance=5cm, green] node[nodestyle] {$a$} (m-2-1)  (m-2-3) edge [style1, out=90, in=90,distance=5cm, green] node[nodestyle, fill=green!20] {$a$} (m-2-1)

Comment: The key is to dynamically generate the color of the nodes without knowing ahead of time what the path color is going to be and without having to put in code to get the the current color with \colorlet{currentcolor}{.}. Want to get this current color ahead of time in the declaration of the style. If that is possible?

Comment: @kunzo: Please add the example to your question. This is unreadable.